# Disable all styles for a container

Tags: css

On my site, I have one CSS file that dictates all the styles for the site, "styles.css".

However, I've recently installed a forum module.

This forum module has its own CSS file, "chatter.css", and it's placed on one of the pages of my site.

Problem is, there's a LOT of conflicting styles going on.

The entire forum is contained within a div with the id of "chatter".

Is there any way I could tell the dom "hey, only apply chatter.css in this div"?

Comment: Can't you just put the chatter.css **under** the styles.css link tag?

Answer (score 1):

You may put entire css file into #chatter between brackets, but that requires usage of precompiler(SASS,Less).

Like that...

`#chatter {
<css file content>
}`